# How to cluster similar text tokens

Tags: text, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I'm working on a project to cluster similar text tokens. The objective is to group tokens that could be typos and also tokens that share similar spelling. Here is a snippet of my data and the expected clusterization:

```
John (cluster 1)
Mike  (cluster 2)
Joe  (cluster 1)
Jon  (cluster 1)
Jony  (cluster 1)
Ajon  (cluster 1)
Brown  (cluster 3)
```

I'm just kicking the tires on clusterization so I'm not sure how can I go about achieving this. Looking through the various clustering techniques in ScikitLearn I came across AffinityPropagation to precompute the similarity but it isnt viable for a large dataset (I have ~200k tokens). All other clustering algorithms need vectors but I'm not sure how to genrate features from these tokens.

Any guidance here would be really appreciative.

Thank you

Comment: what's the origin of these tokens? you could for instance generate an embedding (dense vector of float values) for each token and use these vectors as input to a clustering algorithm

Answer (score 2):

You need a similarity function that encodes the intuition that tokens that differ only by a couple of letters are maybe mispellings.

One way you could do this:

You could transform each token into a vector with 26 dimensions (one for each letter) and each element represents the number of times a given letter appears in the token.

Tokens that differ by a single letter (maybe misspellings) will be close together in that features space because only one element of the array will be different.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like an interesting approach. Let me give it a shot tomorrow

Comment: Well, with this approach Jon and Joe have two letter in common. But "One" and "neo" have all three in common. Letter histograms are okay for language detection, but I wouldn't use them for similarity. At least, use letter bigrams or trigrams...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think clustering is what you should do here.

Because methods such as k-mrans *force* every point into a "cluster". And that probably isn't what you want.

You will also run into the problem that transitively, almost everything is "similar". There are plenty of games where you have to turn one word into another one letter at a time.

Unsteady try to first identify some good values (e.g., by frequency) and then decide with what tolerance to merge alternatives. But without transitive operations. This is *simpler* than clustering and *faster*.